# What is "after_element_html" in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

In magento 2 What I need to use instead of **"after_element_html"**. In magento2 form structure is in xml format, then how do I give note for a particular field in form ? Please provide me a solution

Comment: Have you found answer ?

Comment: Not yet, Because it is a ui component form so failed to add content dynamically

Answer (score 1):

This is something if you want to add after the field element you are adding in admin form

You can added whatever you want html, javascript code, css

Comment: I need to set dynamic data for a particular field in admin form in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

```
$form = $this->_formFactory->create();

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Widget')]);

        $fieldset->addField(
            'select_widget_type',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Widget Type'),
                'title' => __('Widget Type'),
                'name' => 'widget_type',
                'required' => true,
                'onchange' => "wWidget.validateField()",
                'options' => $this->_getWidgetSelectOptions(),
                'after_element_html' => $this->_getWidgetSelectAfterHtml()
            ]
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setId('widget_options_form');
        $form->setMethod('post');
        $form->setAction($this->getUrl('adminhtml/*/buildWidget'));
        $this->setForm($form);
```